# How to use JQuery click method on html lists

Tags: jquery

In my program i have un-ordereded lists which has ordered lists.Requirement is like on clicking the un-ordered list element the child ordered list should open up:

Below is the code that i have written:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>The jQuery Example</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="E:\development\JSPProject\jquery-2.1.4.js">
      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function() {

             $(".GChild").hide();
             $(".child").click(function()
                     {
                 $(".GChild").show();}
                 ); 
             })


      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h3>Welcome </h3>
   <div>
   <ul class="parent">
   <li class ="child">Numbers
   <ol><li class="GChild">one</li><li class="GChild">two</li></ol>
   <li class ="child">Alphabets<ol><li class="GChild">A</li><li class="GChild">B</li></ol></li></ul>
   </div></body>
</html>
```

so here when i click on Numbers the other list also shows up.I know that i didnt specify anything specific to that list.I tried adding this line

```
$(this).filter(".GChild").show();
```

instead of
     `$(".GChild").show();`

But it didn't work.I am new to JQuery so please don't mind if it is silly Question.Is there any way i can achieve "Clicking on (Numbers) it should display One, and Two--------In the same way Alpha-->A,B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fj12z0be/) with your desired functionality.

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".child").click(function(){
        $(this).children().find('.GChild').toggle();
    })
})
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>Welcome </h3>
   <div>
   <ul class="parent">
       <li class ="child">Numbers
           <ol>
               <li class="GChild">one</li>
               <li class="GChild">two</li>
           </ol>
        </li>
       <li class ="child">Alphabets
           <ol>
               <li class="GChild">A</li>
               <li class="GChild">B</li>
           </ol>
        </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You only want to find `.GChild` that are children of the current child you are clicking on. `filter` didn't work because it **reduces** a set of elements by the selector you are passing in. In your case, it was saying filter down this current `child` to a collection that is also a `.GChild`.

You are looking for [jQuery find](http://api.jquery.com/find/), which finds all descendants of the current nodes that match your selector. Change your code to look like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".GChild").hide();
  $(".child").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".GChild").show();
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).find('ol').show();
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8tm66dmo/).